# How to implement dynamic action in Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, dom-events, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

There are two text fields A and B.  When we focus on B field, depending on A value, a popup should be displayed which will have list of values.  User should be able to select one value.  How to accomplish this using dynamic actions in Oracle apex?

Comment: This seems like so straight-forward in that this is just cascading LOVs: are they? If no, why not? And please, why don't you write proper English ("r", "b") - if you don't take the time to properly format your question, why would we take the time to properly answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the popup you can do this with cascading list of values, but since you are asking about a popup list, here is how I would do it.

Create a Classic Report region that has a bind condition to the value returned from "text field A" set the template type to inline-dialog. Create a link in one of the columns that will return its value back to "text field B".

Dynamic Action_1 
When:           on-change
Selection Type: "text field A"
True Action:    Execute PL/SQL Code
PLSQL Code:     null;  -- this is a known hack to set the value of a page item into session state
Items to Submit = "text field A"

Dynamic Action_2
When:           Get Focus
Selection Type: Item = "text field B"
True action(1):    Refresh
Selection Type:    Region holding inline modal
True action(2):    Execute Javascript Code
Code:              openModal('place the static id of the inline modal region');

Inline modal will open you can click the link column created earlier and set the value for "text field B"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to get a popup with list of values. But how can i make them as links and when i select a value in popup, it should be returned to text field B

Comment: I created one of the column(EmpNO) as link and passed below code for Target.  javascript:passBack('#EMPNO#'); Here bug would be the link and when I select bug in popup, that value should be passed back to text field B. In the classic report region, in the header text column, I provided below code.function passBack(passVal1){   opener.document.getElementById("P1_EMPNO").value = passVal1; close();}                                                                                                                      But above code is not passing back the value to text field B.